# How to get data from server in recycler view using data binding

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am using MVVM pattern to fetch data from server in recycler view using data binding.I am doing all server based operations in repository class.

This is what I have done so far:

**MainAcivity.java**

```
ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding;
Repository repo;
EmployAdapter adapter;
List<Employee> empList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);

    setSupportActionBar(activityMainBinding.toolbar);

    repo = new Repository(this);

    activityMainBinding.content.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    activityMainBinding.content.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}
```

**EmployeeAdapter.java**

```
public class EmployAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EmployAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();

public EmployAdapter(Context context, List<Employee> empList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.empList = empList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public EmployAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

   RowLayoutBinding rowLayoutBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);

   ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(rowLayoutBinding);

   return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EmployAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Employee model = empList.get(position);

    holder.rowLayoutBinding.setEmplo(model);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return empList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    RowLayoutBinding rowLayoutBinding;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull RowLayoutBinding itemView) {
        super(itemView.getRoot());

        rowLayoutBinding = itemView;
       }
   }
}
```

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout>

<data>
    <variable
        name="emplo"
        type="Models.Employee"/>
</data>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{emplo.name}"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{emplo.age}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {

@SerializedName("Name")
@Expose
String Name;

@SerializedName("Age")
@Expose
String Age;

public Employee(){

}

public Employee(String Name,String Age){

    this.Name = Name;
    this.Age = Age;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return Age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    Age = age;
}
}
```

**Repository.java**

```
public class Repository {

Context context;

public Repository(Context context){

    this.context = context;

}

 public void getEmployee(){

    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

    apiService.getDataFromServer().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                  .subscribe(getDataObserver());
 }

 private Observer<List<Employee>> getDataObserver(){

    return new Observer<List<Employee>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<Employee> employees) {

            List<Employee> list = employees;

            for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++){

                String name = list.get(i).getName();
                String age = list.get(i).getAge();

                Employee empModel = new Employee(name,age);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

            Toast.makeText(context,"Error: "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
     };
   }
 }
```

Here how can I show list of data fetched form server in repository class in recycler view.Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong or missing any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: just let us know what is the result ? and have you debugged it ? is your adapter working fine?

Comment: and one thing i am curious about is that you havent done any thing in your onComplete() then how you repository is updating the data to adapter ? and why are you doing the whole stuff in on Next? i mean re initialising an object and doing nothing with that object ? what do you expect from this code ?

Comment: Here in onNext() method when I am trying to get NO. of records available it is working fine.

Comment: ahann so  it means your api is working fine, but now what? you need to pass data to adapter so that your adapter start working as well. adapter list is not updated anywhere so how do you expect it that your data will appear in your recycler view

Comment: try setting sample data list in adatper , if that data is visible in recyelerview then you can solve your problem on your own

Comment: Okk bro let me try ....

Comment: see !! issue is that your network layer fecthed the data now you must pass that data to adapter and notify your adapter for data set change , afterwards you adapter will start creating viewholders and then data binding magic will happen